# Cannot bulk load because the file "File.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, blob

I am having the following problem trying to access Azure Blob Store from Azure Sql Database and upload a single blob/image. Getting the above. I have configured SAS. Here are my findings:

- If the container is public, the sql below works without credentials
- When it is private it is possible to access the blob via blob url
  from the browser (using the sas token there)
- If I try to access it via Azure Sql Database (same token) I am
  getting the same error as above:

*"Failed to execute query. Error: Cannot bulk load because the file "POC.png" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)."*

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL MyAzureBlobStorageCredential
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2018-03-28....'
go
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureBlobStorage 
WITH ( TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE, 
LOCATION = 'https://poc.blob.core.windows.net/poc-container',
CREDENTIAL = MyAzureBlobStorageCredential); 
go    
INSERT INTO file111 (col2)
SELECT BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(
 BULK  'POC.png',
DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
 SINGLE_BLOB
) AS DataFile;
```

Comment: Azure Sql Database most probably doesn't have the required permission to the path where POC.png is located.

Comment: On the other hand, as I wrote above - if I set the Azure Blob Access level to Public, then, absolutely the same SQL (only the credentials removed) works fine.

Comment: Another finding: if I create and use SAS only for a specific blob, everything works. The problem is when I create SAS on an upper, storage account level

Comment: Did you generated the SAS with List and Read permissions? In your SAS string you should see "&sp=rl". Also keep in mind that names are case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

What I did was:

- removed any not needed permissions and left only Read and List;
- made sure that Start/End DateTime for the generated with a few days
  in the past/far enough in the future;
- made sure that the {container}{blobname} are the same lower/capital
  letters as in the container;
- there is no backslash at the end of the LOCATION

and it worked. Any of the bullet points which could cause the error message above.

Comment: Congratulations! Please  accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.