# SQL Server - Access denied when reading a file from Azure Blob Storage container using SAS key

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a requirement to read CSV files from an Azure blob storage. So far, this is throwing access denied errors every time I run my query:

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL <myScopedCredential> 
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'sv=2021-06-08&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rl&se=2023-03-31T09:38:05Z&st=2022-09-01T02:38:05Z...';

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <myExternalDatasource>
WITH ( 

    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE
    , LOCATION = 'https://<myResource>.blob.core.windows.net/<myContainer>'
    , CREDENTIAL= <myScopedCredential> --> 
);

SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET (
    BULK  '<folderName>/<fileName>.csv'
   , DATA_SOURCE = '<myExternalDatasource>'
   , FORMAT ='CSV'
   , FORMATFILE='<formatFilesFolderName>/<formatfileName>.fmt'
   , FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = '<myExternalDatasource>'
   , FIRSTROW = 2
) AS test
```

Below are some more details on how everything was setup:

- The storage account kind is of **BlockBlobStorage**.
- In the **Firewalls and virtual networks** setting, it is only **Enabled
  from selected virtual networks and IP addresses**. I already added my
  public IP address, as well as the IP address of Azure SQL Server
  which I got from here:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/connectivity-architecture?view=azuresql#gateway-ip-addresses
- The whole process works if I set it to **Enabled from all networks**.
  The SQL server and the storage account lives within the same resource
  group.
- I also configured a VNet that is both added for both of the
  resource.
- Saw this thread which is exactly similar to my issue, however the accepted answer is not working from my end: [Cannot bulk load because the file "File.csv" could not be opened. Operating system error code 5(Access is denied.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58340185/cannot-bulk-load-because-the-file-file-csv-could-not-be-opened-operating-syst)

I checked all the documentations regarding SAS access keys, database scoped credentials, external data sources and VNet networking and I don't see any limitations for SAS key access to be denied. Did I miss a configuration setup? I find it a little weird that in most cases, they are recommending to setup the storage account to be Enabled from all networks, which might be a security issue.

Comment: please have look on this [Document](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql/how-to-read-files-from-blob-storage-with-storage-firewall/m-p/1404901#:~:text=Reading%20files%20from%20Blob%20Storage,database%20and%20then%20whitelist%20it.) if it helps you.